# Use Observable in Template

Tags: angular, typescript, angularfire2

I am trying to use an observable in my template by:

```
<md-nav-list>
    <a md-list-item *ngIf="!isAuth() | async" [routerLink]="['login']" (click)="sidenav.toggle()">Login</a>
    <a md-list-item *ngIf="isAuth() | async" (click)="logout()" (click)="sidenav.toggle()">Logout</a>
</md-nav-list>
```

and in my module:

```
isAuth(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.loginservice.getAuthenticated()
    .map(user => {
      if (user) {
        if (user.hasOwnProperty('uid')) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    })
}
```

So my problem:

if i am loggedin and the observable returns true -> cool my menu item appears

but if the observable returns false -> my menu is empty -> whats wrong ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your expression `*ngIf="!isAuth() | async"` is going to be interpreted as:

```
isAuth() -> returns observable
!isAuth() -> returns false because of !
!isAuth() | async -> actually trying to subscribe on false which should fail
```

Just use `!(isAuth() | async)` instead.

Another problem you have is that you call the server twice while loading the template. This is something that you probably don't want to do.

And finally, this

```
isAuth(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.loginservice.getAuthenticated()
    .map(user => {
      if (user) {
        if (user.hasOwnProperty('uid')) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    })
}
```

can be written as

```
this.loginservice.getAuthenticated()
    .map(user => user && user.hasOwnProperty('uid'))
```

and with angular 5+ as

```
this.loginservice.getAuthenticated().pipe(
  map(user => user && user.hasOwnProperty('uid'))
)
```

Comment: Nicely explained +1, but how can he handle exact opposite case?

Comment: Regarding the first problem, you should explain how it can be fixed with parentheses.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior well that's of course easy if you mean this `!(isAuth() | async)`, however I don't think that subscribing two times on the same observable is a good idea here. I would subscribe to it on the component level instead...

Comment: thank you very much, that helps a lot ;) so i make an own menu on each case where the visibility depends on the observable